# @turf/boolean-contains returns false, even though one polygon is fully contained in another

Tags: polygon, leaflet, geojson, turf, typescript

I'm having trouble with some polygons.

I'm using BooleanContains from the turf library to try to highlight some errors in my map. The thing is that in some polygons BooleanContains acts weird. For example in this polygon: [image: polygon one]
We can see that the error polygon is a little over the bigger polygon. But it still gives me problems if i do something like this: [image: polygonTwo]

And in the second case it makes no sense the problem.

My code looks like this:

[image: poly]
[image: poly4]

My intention is to make the polygon that is inside smaller with the transformScale to give it a margin of error. But it would seem that it is not enough for this case, which does work with other polygons.